# What does ItemAverage Recommender do in Mahout

Tags: recommender-system

The description sounds to me as if it makes a MostPopular recommendation. But the MostPopular recommendation I did myself got much better results. So what does this recommender really return?

It is a Boolean data set. And I just count the occurrences of an item and sort them with the counts.

Answer (score 0):

It is a "most popular" algorithm indeed. But if you are using data with no ratings, then the ratings are implicitly 1, and so every item's average rating is 1. The result is random. That is to say: don't use it without item ratings to average.